# Regex error when trying to build with PyTube and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

I’m getting this error below trying to run this code. I want to build a youtube video downloader with tkinter and pytube

`pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*`

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube

window = Tk()

def downloaderr():
     yt = YouTube(videolink.get())
     yt.streams.first().download()


window.geometry('750x750')
window.title("YouTube Video Downloader")
lbl = Label(window,text="Video Linkini Yapıştırıp Butona Tıklayınız")
lbl.grid(column=5,row=10)
videolink = Entry(window,width=70)
videolink.grid
btn = Button(window,text= "Click to Download",command=downloaderr())
btn.grid(column=15,row=15) 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: where is the code??

Comment: I forgot to add code. I'am sorry

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i've added the error.  @alexpdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are calling the `downloaderr`  in the `Button` assignment.

```
btn = Button(window,text= "Click to Download",command=downloaderr())
```

should be

```
btn = Button(window,text= "Click to Download",command=downloaderr)
```

However you will still get that error when a user presses the button.  The reason for the error is whatever `videolink.get()` returns is not a match for the regex pattern required by pytube.

Comment: Thank u mate. This solved problem for me. All worked fine.